# Docker mount happens before or after entrypoint execution

Tags: docker, spring-boot

I'm building a Docker image to run my Spring Boot based application. I want to have user to be able to feed a run time properties file by mounting the folder containing application.properties into container. Here is my Dockerfile,

```
FROM java:8

RUN mkdir /app
RUN mkdir /app/config
ADD myapp.jar /app/

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app/myapp.jar"]
```

When kicking off container, I run this,

```
docker run -d -v /home/user/config:/app/config myapp:latest
```

where `/home/user/config` contains the `application.properties` I want the jar file to pick up during run time.

However this doesn't work, the app run doesn't pick up this mounted properties file, it's using the default one packed inside the jar. But when I `exec` into the started container and manually run the entrypoint cmd again, it works as expected by picking up the file I mounted in. So I'm wondering is this something related to how mount works with entrypoint? Or I just didn't write the Dockerfile correctly for this case?

Comment: When you run it manually, what directory do you run it from? `/` or `/app`?

Comment: Sorry replied too early. I guess you mean where do I run after `exec` into container right? I run it under `/app`, so the cmd I manually ran was just `java -jar myapp.jar`

Comment: Oh, just gave it a quick try to run the cmd somewhere else, then it's not using the mounted in config. So I guess the problem is I didn't fully understand the usage of how Spring Boot pick up external config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Boot [searches](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) for `application.properties` inside a `/config` subdirectory of *the current directory* (among other locations). In your case, current directory is `/` (docker default), so you need to change it to `/app`. To do that, add

```
WORKDIR /app
```

before the `ENTRYPOINT` line.

---

And to answer your original question: mounts are done before anything inside the container is run.

Comment: Yup, just did this and it works. Should have read the document page a little more carefully. Thanks a lot for the quick help!