# Docker ENTRYPOINT to run after Volume Mount

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My Dockerfile have a script to run on ENTRYPOINT.
The container is defined to run with a volume mount where my code resides,  and it needs to run a set of commands once the container is up with volume mount.

But from errors I get while running container, which tends me to believe the Docker Volume Mount happens after the ENTRYPOINT script execution?

I sure can run the commands with *docker exec* options once container is up. But that makes it not that smooth and more lines of code. Is there any work-around, may be with docker-compose?

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM my-container
WORKDIR /my-mount-dir

ADD startup-script.sh /root/startup-script.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/root/startup-script.sh"]
```

**Docker Run :**

docker run -itd -v /home/user/directory:/my-mount-dir build-container

**Note :** startup-script.sh includes commands which is supposed to interact with files fron the mounted directory.

Comment: What is your docker version?

Comment: Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87

Comment: The default behavior of docker is to set up the before your docker entrypoint process starts. Can you include a more complete example illustrating that the volume really isn't available?

Comment: From errors, it was file-not found like thing. I couldn't include without compromising code

Comment: This question premise conflicts with this answer: [And to answer your original question: mounts are done before anything inside the container is run.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38469882/5579463) - which one is correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the solution you want but I've been using this run command which uses cat command to supply my `script.sh` to the container:

```
docker run -it --name=some_name --rm \
  -v "host/path:/path/inside/container" \
  image_name \
  /bin/bash  -c "$(cat ./script.sh)"
```

In this case the script runs after the mount is complete. I am sure of this as I've used the files from the mounted volumes in the script.

Answer (score 7):

The entrypoint script does run after the volume mount. I encountered a similar issue but it was actually due to using single quotes around the entrypoint instead of double quotes. Because of this, the container was falling back to using the default entrypoint of `/bin/sh`. As your question is already answered, I'm leaving this for others who end up here via Google.

This:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

Not this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ['entrypoint.sh']
```

Comment: Also in docker guest not to automatically assume, expect to be in a project dir, be it mounted docker-compose, or copied both docker-run, compose, since it might be tempting to assume cwd is there, if you run entrypoint from the mounted project, thus to address it relatively, would either fail or even do wrong fallback to unexpected, since a bit confusing "./entrypoint.sh" might make you think its relative to docker directory, while normally even it refers to /entrypoint.sh

Answer (score 5):

I have seen that in some of my scripts and it looks like file system cache problem to me... I use the following hack in my docker file and it works like a charm:

`ENTRYPOINT ls /my-mount-dir  &&  /root/startup-script.sh`

But then you cannot use the list form for the ENTRYPOINT

Comment: It worked for me! 
When I try to execute script as a entrypoint mapped through volume - it's invisible. But when I first list files inside this volume and then execute - it works.